# foreign key to a table having more than one primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

so this is my double primary key table

```
create table order_mattress
(
order_number int,
mattress_id int ,
primary key (order_number,mattress_id) 
);
```

this is my second table

```
create table mattress
(
mattress_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
mattress_name varchar(25)
);
```

i want to mattress_id in the table mattress to be a foreign key to mattress_id in  the table order_mattress how is that possible, without having any problem because of the double primary key in the firsttable

Comment: Are you saying that you can't create a mattress without there being an order first? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That's one primary key, consisting of two columns (aka composite primary key). BTW, isn't the fk supposed to go in the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'd change it so that you have 3 tables as opposed to 2:

Simple order table to hold unique order number:

```
create table orders
(
    order_number int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

Mattress table that hold all unique mattresses:

```
create table mattress
(
    mattress_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    mattress_name varchar(25)
);
```

The order mattress table, then links mattresses to orders with foreign keys.

```
create table order_mattress
(
    order_number int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES orders(order_number),
    mattress_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES mattress(mattress_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the direction wrong - if the `mattress` table describes mattresses, the `mattress_order` table should have a foreign key to it:

```
ALTER TABLE order_mattress
ADD FOREIGN KEY (mattress_id)
REFERENCES mattress(mattress_id)
```

The other direction is indeed impossible as `mattress_id` is not unique in `order_mattress`.